# Index - Offset - Array Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I am using OFFSET function to transpose the "Question" columns to rows so every row would correspond to a Link/Question combination as shown in the 2nd table.

I can hide values in columns A & B if column C is blank but this is taking TOO MUCH space in my table (*my full data consist of 11 questions, and hundreds of rows, which won't fit in my sheet if I create a row for every Question column*). I need to transform my functions to an array formula that would only populate a row for every Link/non blank Question combo, so that row 9 in the image below won't show up and its formula won't exist at all. I'm using Gsheets.[image]

1st function for column A
2nd function for column C

```
OFFSET($A$2,FLOOR((ROW($A1)-ROW($A$1))/2,1),0)
OFFSET($C$2,FLOOR((ROW(A1)-ROW($A$1))/2,1),MOD((ROW(A1)-ROW($A$1))/2,1)*2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try in A7:

```
=query({query(A2:C3,"select A,B,C where C is not NULL");query(A2:D3,"select A,B,D where D is not NULL")})
```

As mentioned by [@Annan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2118/annan) (thank you!) [the outer query is redundant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51484892/index-offset-array-formula/51485435?noredirect=1#comment101794047_51485435).

Comment: What does the outer `query` do?

Answer (score 0):

This really IS the same as in excel.. but I can't help the " only populate a row for every Link/non blank Question combo" part. Try :

```
A7    =if($C7="","",index($A$2:$D$3,int((row(A7)-7)/(COLUMNS($A$2:$D$3)-2))+1,match(A$6,$A$1:$D$1,0)))

B7    =if($C7="","",index($A$2:$D$3,int((row(B7)-7)/(COLUMNS($A$2:$D$3)-2))+1,match(B$6,$A$1:$D$1,0)))

C7    =index($A$2:$D$3,int((row(C7)-7)/(COLUMNS($A$2:$D$3)-2))+1,(2+if(mod(row(C6)-5,COLUMNS($A$2:$D$3)-2)=0,COLUMNS($A$2:$D$3)-2,mod(row(C6)-5,COLUMNS($A$2:$D$3)-2))))
```

and drag to A10:C10.

Hope it help it'll be useful though.. :)

Comment: Should I put it as a comment for the Q ?

Comment: Thanks for the note Really appreciate it. (:

Comment: No problem... Its just business. /(^_^)